# How to store multiple values in useState of api response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm calling a api with another api like

**First api have list like a labels:-**

```
{
    "body": [
        {
            "label": "label one",
            "inputVal": "input value one"
        },
        {
            "label": "label two",
            "inputVal": "input value two"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second api will validate each label and input as we are using in first api:-**
so I'm calling second api two time (it may be more than two) because I need to validate two label and input as in first api.

```js
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState([]);

async function firstApi() {
    axios
      .post('first_api_url', {
        title: "title",
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          res.data.body.forEach((val) => {
            secondApi();
          });
        }
      });
  }

async function secondApi() {
    axios
      .post('second_api_url', {
        titleSecondApi: "titleSecondApi",
      })
      .then((res) => {
       if (res.data.body.msg) {
          setInputVal([res.data.body.msg]);
          console.log(inputVal);
        }
      });
}
```

Now I'm getting second api response only last response but I need all response in an array.

I'm using inputVal useState for that but not getting all the values in array how to get it?

Thanks for your efrorts!

Comment: how does the response from second API looks as ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your point correctly, you may try to change your code like that:

```
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState([]);

async function firstApi() {
    axios
      .post('first_api_url', {
        title: "title",
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          res.data.body.forEach((val) => {
            secondApi();
          });
        }
      });
  }

async function secondApi() {
    axios
      .post('second_api_url', {
        titleSecondApi: "titleSecondApi",
      })
      .then((res) => {
       if (res.data.body.msg) {
          setInputVal(prev=> {
            return [...prev, res.data.body.msg]
          });
          console.log(inputVal);
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are over-writing your state with a new array. You need to preserve your previous responses. To do that, you need to update your setter in the second API's then block like the following:

```js
setInputVal(previous => [...previous, res.data.body.msg]);
```

You can learn more about [spreading in javascript arrays here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals).